# Possibility to hook into context swap during spring tests with different active profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-profiles

We currently have some Spring integration tests (using spring-boot framework + Junit) that require different setup in the database. We can easily achieve this by setting our tests to load different `@ActiveProfiles` and have the database populated for them internally. However the issue is that when you have:

```
Test A -> Active Profile 1
Test B -> Active Profile 2
Test C -> Active Profile 1
Test D -> Active Profile 1
```

Spring won't reload the context for Test C but rather use the same one that was previously created when running Test A.
We can solve this if we have a "Hook" (possibly in the test runner?) or a `SpringContextEvent` of some sort that notifies us when spring is swapping between these context (so in the above example between test A and B,  and between Test B and C). I could not find anything of the sort (possibly near the `TestContextManager` class). Is there something we can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DirtiesContext to instruct the test context manager to recreate the context.

Comment: It would work if i have all test that are using active profile 2 marked also with dirties context, but that will quickly result in a large amount of tests having to recreate the context
cause say for example you have tests running profiles in this order 1, 2, 1, 2. You'd need to mark the tests 2,1 both with dirties context to recreate the data, and add in the fact that there is no guarnatee that tests run in the same order, so all tests would need to have DirtiesContext